# How I can get all the points of a polygon in a shapeFile .shp using GeoTools?

Tags: java, javafx, shapefile, geotools

This is my first question in stackoverflow so I hope that I am doing it in the right way.

I am using geotools to read a shapeFile (.shp) and I cannot find the function to get all the points of the polygon. By now I have the following code:

```
public class ImportShapeFileService implements ImportShapeFileServiceInterface {

    @Override
    public void loadShapeFile(File shapeFile) throws MdfException {

        FileDataStore store;
        try {
            store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(shapeFile);
            SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = store.getFeatureSource();
            SimpleFeatureCollection collection = featureSource.getFeatures();

            ReferencedEnvelope env = collection.getBounds();
            double left = env.getMinX();
            double right = env.getMaxX();
            double top = env.getMaxY();
            double bottom = env.getMinY();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the four bounds of the shapFile, but not the points of the polygon that contains, is it possible to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: When I said the points I meant the latitude and longitude of each point of the figure.

Comment: `SimpleFeatureIterator` and examine the geometry, for [example](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/tutorial/geometry/geometrycrs.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do with the points, I'd do something like:

```
try(SimpleFeatureIterator itr1 = features.features()){
  while(itr1.hasNext()){
     SimpleFeature f = itr1.next();
     Geometry g = (Geometry)f.getDefaultGeometry();
     Coordinate[] coords = g.getCoordinates();
     // do something with the coordinates
   }
}
```

If you must have `Point` rather than just the coordinates (and you are sure you have polygons then you could use:

```
  Geometry g = (Geometry)f.getDefaultGeometry();
  for(int i=0;i<g.getNumPoints();i++) {
    Point p=((Polygon)g).getExteriorRing().getPointN(i);
  }
```

Comment: `g.getCoordinates()` doesn't exist anymore in version "23-SNAPSHOT". :/

Comment: It seems to see https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Geometry.html#getCoordinates--  Geometry is a JTS object not a GeoTools one.

Comment: I see, thanks! Do you happen to know how to get a `CoordinateXYMZ` object from it? `g.getCoordinate()` returns a normal `Coordinate` one that has an `M` value but it's `NaN`, even though the shapefile has properly set `M` values.

Comment: you need to ask a new question

Comment: Yes, I planning on doing that if you didn't know the answer.